# Scripted solution to penetrating meshes (Maya)

Tags: maya, python

I have thousands of human meshes that are wearing garment meshes (some with looser garments and others with tighter garments). The problem is that the garments are penetrating the human mesh in certain areas. I found this https://manual.reallusion.com/Character_Creator/ENU/1/08_Cloth/Conforming_Clothing.htm to be a helpful solution to the problem. Essentially, the garment vertices are popped out manually so that they do not penetrate the human mesh. Unfortunately, this manual process is impractical for my large data set.

Is there a way I could script this in Maya using Python or MEL? For instance, is it possible to do the following: `if garment vertex in human mesh than pop out vertex`?

Comment: Hi there. I don't think that this question falls within the expertise of graphic designers. You'll have a better chance in techartists communities (http://polycount.com for instance)

Comment: i wonder since it will snap to the original couldnt you just offset all points. In anycase this is not so easy problem. Finding inside out need to use the api so mel is out of question. Python possible, i have a [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135614/querying-of-a-point-is-within-a-mesh-maya-python-api/18175481#18175481) on stackoverflow. But i have no maya at the moment so i cant test untill monday. Technically what you want is a combinaton of what i wrote and a move command. But its quite computationally intensive so if your meshes are HUGE then youd need to other things

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy i agree though SO would work similar questions have been answered there. Though i dont know not a lot of people willing to go this far for free in the world (and i have stopped myself mostly).

Comment: I'll post it to SO when the bounty time frame expires. Thank you for the suggestions.